# Upload homepage

Tags: html, asp.net

i have a question, where i hope someone can guide me.

I have made an homepage, and everything is working great, besides a few things that is miss placed in Firefox, and looks perfect in Chrome.

As well the site, looks abit weird on phones.

www.securehome.nu is the homepage.

Basic knowedge about the homepage

- The site is created in Visual Studio
- The site is build up around a MasterPage

Info about the problems
 - The menu bar have some borders (the lines that splits each menu field from each other, those borders aint positionen the same place in firefox and chrome.
 - On the phone, there is a white field in the bottom, even that the wrapper is height 100%, and it works smoothly on computer browsers.

I can easily put the whole site into a winrar document for download if someone wants to try play around with it, and help me what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see there is no problem with my both browser they are looking same and there is no  responsive view for mobile of your site

Comment: Hmm, that is kinda weird. can you take a picture of the site from both browsers and upload here :)